# How do I tell XSLT script to bypass specific text?

Tags: xslt

How do I tell my XSLT script not to copy the paragraph containing "Strategy:"?

Sorry for all the code but this should include all the info that's giving me the problem.

Here is my XSLT template:

```
<xsl:when test="xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:answer']">
                            <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:answer']">
                                <xsl:variable name="answerNum" select="position()"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="feedbackPara"
                                    select="../following-sibling::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']/xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation-section'][1]/xhtml:p[$answerNum]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="feedbackParaText"
                                    select="../following-sibling::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']/xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation-section'][1]/xhtml:p[$answerNum]/text()[string-length(normalize-space()) &gt; 1][preceding-sibling::xhtml:span[contains(@class, 'mark-')[last()]] | preceding-sibling::xhtml:b[1]]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="correctSpan"
                                    select="../following-sibling::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']/xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation-section'][1]/xhtml:p[$answerNum]/xhtml:span"/>
                                <!--<xsl:variable name="tokenizefeedbackPara">
                            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(normalize-space($feedbackPara), '\s')"/>
                        </xsl:variable>-->
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when
                                            test="//xhtml:span[@property = 'ktp:interactionType'][node() = 'single-select' or node() = 'multiple-select']">
                                            <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation"
                                                class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
                                                    <xsl:call-template name="assignID"/>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <section property="ktp:explanation-section"
                                                    typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback"
                                                    class="ktp-explanation-section">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
                                                        <xsl:call-template name="assignID"/>
                                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
                                                            <xsl:call-template name="assignID"/>
                                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                            <xsl:when
                                                                test="$feedbackPara[xhtml:b | xhtml:span | xhtml:i | xhtml:sup | xhtml:sub]">
                                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:when test="$feedbackPara[xhtml:i | xhtml:sup | xhtml:sub]">
                                                                        <xsl:apply-templates
                                                                            select="$feedbackPara/node()[position() &gt; 2] except $correctSpan"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        <xsl:value-of
                                                                            select="
                                                                            substring-after($feedbackParaText, functx:substring-before-match(
                                                                            $feedbackParaText, '[A-Z0-9]'))"
                                                                        />
                                                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                </xsl:choose>
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                                    select="substring-after($feedbackPara, ') ')"/>
                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                    </p>
                                                </section>
                                            </section>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise/>

                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
```

This is the output I'm getting. For answer choice 1, it's outputting the content after the "Strategy:". I need it to skip the strategy paragraph and only include the paragraphs that start with 1), 2), 3), and 4)

```
<ol class="ktp-answer-set">
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Chef salad, crackers, and iced
                  tea.
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Recall foods that are
                           high in protein.
                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">Broiled fish, cream of tomato soup
                  topped with grated cheese, and custard. 
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>A chef salad contains pieces of ham and cheese, which have protein. Crackers and iced
                           tea do not contain protein. The majority of foods selected do not contain protein.

                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Peanut butter and jelly sandwich,
                  chips, and fruit drink.
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>All foods selected contain protein. Protein can be increased by adding skim milk to
                           appropriate foods, adding grated cheese to foods, using peanut butter as a spread
                           on fruits and vegetables, using yogurt as a topping for fruit and cake. 
                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Turkey sandwich with lettuce and
                  tomato, potato salad, and milk. 
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Peanut butter contains protein, but the other foods do not.</p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
            </ol>
```

This is the desired output which places the explanation for answer choice 1) under the correct answer choice:

```
<ol class="ktp-answer-set">
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Chef salad, crackers, and iced
                  tea.
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>A chef salad contains pieces of ham and cheese, which have protein. Crackers and iced tea do not contain protein. The majority of foods selected do not contain protein.
                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">Broiled fish, cream of tomato soup
                  topped with grated cheese, and custard. 
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>All foods selected contain protein. Protein can be increased by adding skim milk to appropriate foods, adding grated cheese to foods, using peanut butter as a spread on fruits and vegetables, using yogurt as a topping for fruit and cake.

                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Peanut butter and jelly sandwich,
                  chips, and fruit drink.
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Peanut butter contains protein, but the other foods do not.
                        </p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
               <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Turkey sandwich with lettuce and
                  tomato, potato salad, and milk. 
                  <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
                     <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Turkey and milk contain protein, but potato salad very little if any.</p>
                     </section>
                  </section>
               </li>
            </ol>
```

This is the content from where I need to only copy the text that starts with 1), 2), 3), and 4) and skip the Strategy paragraph:

```
<section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:summary" data-title="Summary" class="ktp-explanation-section">

                  <p><b>Strategy:</b> Recall foods that are high in protein.
                  </p>
                  <p>1) A chef salad contains pieces of ham and cheese, which have protein. Crackers and
                     iced tea do not contain protein. The majority of foods selected do not contain protein.
                  </p>
                  <p>2) <b>CORRECT</b> — All foods selected contain protein. Protein can be increased by adding skim milk
                     to appropriate foods, adding grated cheese to foods, using peanut butter as a spread
                     on fruits and vegetables, using yogurt as a topping for fruit and cake.
                  </p>
                  <p>3) Peanut butter contains protein, but the other foods do not.</p>
                  <p>4) Turkey and milk contain protein, but potato salad very little if any.</p>

               </section>
```

Comment: You should provide more than a snippet. It is not clear for us v.gr. to know the value of `$feedbackPara`.

Comment: I added more info. Please let me know if that makes it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: A [mcve] would be very useful.

Comment: I removed as much as I could from the template. I didn't want to get rid of any relevant code.

Comment: It still cannot be run.

Comment: For it to be run successfully I'd have to provide the full script. It's all intertwined.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reverse engineer a specification from one example, especially as you haven't even shown us the expected output. Producing a decent answer requires knowing what the stylesheet should do with documents that are slightly different (or indeed, very different) from the one shown. The code you'be provided seems very sensitive to ephemeral details of the content, such as what's in bold and italics: but you know your content better than we do, so perhaps you can rely on this.

Also, your code contains two variables $feedbackPara and $feedbackParaText, and it's not clear what the values of these variables are.

I don't know if I've really worked out your requirements, but I would expect to see something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="x:section">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="x:p"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:p[contains(., 'Strategy')]"/>

<xsl:template match="x:p">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I added more info. Please let me know if that makes it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: How can I debug your code when it contains lines like `$content-item-name = $input-qid` and I have no idea what is in either of these two variables?

Comment: content-item-name comes from this line ```<span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="n000003"></span>```. I enter a list in the parameters containing the items I want the script to run on. In this case I enter n000003. That part of the scripts work as it's supposed to. It's just telling the script not to process that Strategy: paragraph I can't figure out. Would providing the full script be beneficial? It's a long script though.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to to its essentials by cutting out the irrelevant detail, and then show us the reduced problem in full. (Often, doing this will help you understand the problem better yourself.)